# XCode 4.3 "Failed to load project at 'project path' for an unknown reason"

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I keep on getting the above error when I try to open my project in Xcode 4.3.

"Failed to load project at 'project path' for an unknown reason"

I ended up creating a new project and then copying the source files over to the new project, but after closing the project - when I go to open it up again I get the same error. It is only happening with this one project.

Has this happened to anyone else? Any ideas on what could be causing it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redid the project copying the source code files in one at a time to figure out which was causing the problem. It turns out that it was an image file with a unicode text object in the file path. Apparently, Xcode will not re-open if the file path contains a new unicode (6.1) character. I just renamed the image and things were great.